# Blurred fonts, lines in on-the-fly generated SVG into canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, svg

I have a code what can generate a `SVG` image from `HTML` table. [JSFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/netdjw/D5kgu/)

There is a problem with generated `image`: every elements are blurred, like you zoom in the image.

I was tried to change the font size, using `pt`, `em` or `px`... tried change the width and height of the table... same result.

I want to see my `HTML` `table` 1:1 in the `SVG`. What is the problem here?

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work for me in either firefox or safari (webkit). what browser are you using?

Comment: ah, got it sorta working in chrome

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in this code.

First is that you are dynamically scaling the canvas as needed. When you scale the canvas, you are scaling the pixels in the 2dcontext area of the canvas too, and they don't scale like html or svg will; they scale like an image made of pixels. This is the cause of the blurriness.

The second problem was masked by the first one; the svg document you are creating doesn't knw how to autosize itself, so setting the width and height of the svg element to 100% does nothing. So, my recommendation:

1. Create the canvas tag on the fly in jQuery, and create it with the width and height attributes set to the width of the table's border-box. Do this in the place in the code where you previously resized the canvas element. the most easy way would be to replace the canvas element with a div:

   ```
   <div id="canvasy"></div>
   ```

   then, append the canvas element to it dynamically like this:

   ```
   $('#canvasy').append('<canvas id="canvas" width="'+($(id).width()+5)+'" height="'+($(id).height()+5)+'"></canvas>');
   ```
2. When you build the svg, use the same width/height values in your svg element.

Here's a [working version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5kgu/4/)